# Proving that $\{a^n b^2 a^n \mid n\ge 0\}$ is a regular language

Tags: automata

From what I understood, a L is regular if you can draw a FSA or a Regex. For the L={$a^n b^2 a^n | n≥0$}, I've written out a Finite State Automata and a Regex. I'm not sure if this is correct, so can someone verify this for me?

[image]

$ stands for epsilon by the way.

Regex: a*ba*

Thank you!

Comment: That language is not regular; you can use the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to prove this. Your automaton also generates strings like $abbaa$, with different numbers of $a$s before and after the $bb$; these are not in $L$.

Comment: What you've drawn accepts $a^* b^2 a^*$.

Comment: Oh I see. $a^n$ and $b^n$ mean that there should be an equal amount of a's and b's??

Comment: What a silly beginners mistake. Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb to determine whether a language is regular or not is if it requires *counting*. To form a valid string, your automaton would have to count the number of $a$'s it is adding after the two $b$'s, so that it matches the same number of $a$'s at the start. That is why it is not regular, because FSAs/regular expressions cannot count.

As mentioned in the comments, you can verify that this language is not regular formally using the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

The next level up from FSAs are [push-down automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton). A push-down automaton can (sort of) count, since it would use a stack to keep track of the number of $a$'s. This means that it is at least a deterministic context-free language.

Comment: I've just tried to prove it is not a regular language by using the pumping lemma. I've taken the pumping length to be 7, so my string would look like this

aaaaaaabbaaaaaaa

The part that I am unsure of is the 'cases' part during the division into xyz.
Do I have to take case 1:y contains 'a', case 2:'b', case 3: 'ab' and case 4: 'ba'?

Then I prove that it is not a regular language, by saying that i=2, which gives me for example the string:
aaaaaaabbbaaaaaaa with the case 2. because this string is not part of L. Is this the correct way? Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: If this is incorrect, do I have to ignore $b^2$ in the proof of the pumping Lemma regarding the division into xyz?

Comment: @ano you *can not* define the pumping length when using the pumping lemma to prove a language non-regular.

Comment: @ano vonbrand is right, see how you should use the lemma in the "use of the lemma" section of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_the_lemma). The example there is identical to yours, minus the two $b$'s in the middle.

Comment: I just read the article and there are a few things that i am confused about:

The constant P, how do you determine how long it is? and how do you know $a^p b^p$ is longer than p?